# A pretty and feature rich Git GUI for Linux

Tags: git, user-interface, dvcs, gitk

I was checking out for a *rich GUI* for Git on Linux. As of late, I have started using it a lot and find that even though command-line is very useful, I would still want a GUI at my disposal since I am not still very much aware with the advanced features.

I came across [this question on Stack Overflow before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux), but I still have to ask this question again, as that question doesn't have my answer

- I have used *git-cola* and [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk), but they look half-baked and gitk looks like I am working on some other desktop environment. All the features I require in gitGUI is not in either of them.
- I tried *giggle*, but it is more useful for watching diffs
- I tried QGit, but it is not fully complete.

Now let me tell how I want a foo-Git-GUI to look like:

- You can have a look at [`Bzr Explorer`](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/). It is highly usable and has many more features than many of the above mentioned GUIs

Is there any Git GUI which looks like the above example I posted above?

Comment: The git homepage has a list: https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux

Comment: This question was asked in 2010, when this question was relevant

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I find myself using mainly `gitg` in combination with the command line for more complicated tasks.

Source repository: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg.

Recently, a new version 0.3.2 has been released, which is a rewrite using [Vala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(programming_language)). It's not yet feature-complete compared to the old 0.2 series, but the refactor is expected to speed up future development.

Also, there are normally [PPAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Package_Archives) on [Launchpad](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Launchpad) which contain a more up-to-date version than the standard repository.

[image]

[image]

Comment: although it looks good, unfortunately it does almost nothing. :-(

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call staging, line-based staging, committing, branching, tagging, cherry-picking, patching, browsing, showing diffs, etc... "almost nothing". ;-) - At least for me, personally, it covers about 80% of what I typically do in a repo.

Comment: fair enough... I rephrase... "it's useful for local work, but not for remote collaboration"

Comment: Does this project have a website?  Looks cool, but hard to find info.

Comment: Hm, the homepage seems to be currently offline. I added a link to the source repository, the only meaningful page I could find (apart from an old github page)

Comment: Gitg sure looks nice, but looks like it's a dead project.

Comment: @Travis: Well there's not much public activity, but if you check the git log, there is still work happening: http://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/log/

Comment: Ahh, good to know. Thanks @Christoph , just installed it with apt-get install gitg and trying it out.

Comment: @TravisR: just FYI, there's PPAs on Launchpad with a more up-to-date version (2.5.0), e.g. https://launchpad.net/~weits666/+archive/ppa https://launchpad.net/~xperimental/+archive/ppa if you want to try that.

Comment: Wow, nice. This looks like a port of GitX from OS X, my favourite Git frontend. Wish the font would be smaller. Aww, it doesn't support pipe like GItX (`git diff | gitx`) for a very nice readable diff.

Comment: TBH, for a GUI gitg leaves a lot to be desired .. the 80% Christoph mentions is really pushing it, and comes with bad functionality & user experience.  Compared to Source Tree it's really not up to par... And yet I've found nothing on *nix based systems that is.

Answer (score 21):

[Smartgit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) seems to be pretty feature rich. It allows committing, rebasing, visualizing branch history, etc. It's not open source, but it is free to use for [non-commercial projects](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/license.html#3.2.1).

I installed it by downloading from the site, untarring and running `bin/smartgit.sh`.  There are also [PPAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Package_Archives) like [this one](https://launchpad.net/%7Eeugenesan/+archive/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=150&start=150) that have it.

[GitKraken](http://www.gitkraken.com/), which is a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)/[Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) based client has also entered into the foray with both *.deb* and stand-alone binaries. [Here are screenshots](http://blog.axosoft.com/2015/10/13/gitkraken-git-gui-client-mac-windows-linux/#gallery-1) from its announcement.

Comment: this is by far the most useful git gui i have ever found. thank you!

Comment: upvoted, I love this. Just that it's not open source, but who care, sublime is not open source either!
I prefer CLI most of the time, just except for git/hg. And the GUI of company driven apps are usually better.

Comment: Holy crap! I never thought I'd see a Git GUI of this caliber on Linux!

Comment: I prefer Smartgit to GitKraken because GitKraken required me to do a login to either github or gitkraken. All I wanted was a pretty git-diff!

Answer (score 20):

I doubt you're going to find what you want if you haven't already. Linux users tend to be quite happy using CLIs so there's not nearly so strong a drive for a huge GUI.

That said, you've somehow missed looking at git-gui. git-gui and gitk are the two that are actually part of the git suite, and they're designed to complement each other - gitk for looking at history and diffs, git-gui for making commits, merging, fetching, pushing...

Comment: Thanks Jefromi, I can understand that Linux users are happy with cli, but still I find that good GUIs are available for Bazaar but not for GIT. This is why I asked the question

Comment: OTOH git-cola is just too confusing. It may be good, but just too complicated to use. Compare it against `Bzr Explorer` and see.

Comment: I didn't say anything about git cola.

Comment: I can't figure out how to launch git-gui.  Not in Linux' menu, and terminal "git-gui" does nothing, and "whereis git-gui" shows me a location or two but no suggestions.

Comment: @Smandoli It's a git command: `git gui`

Comment: Oh!  Thanks!  (A) how obvious.  (B)  Why don't they SAY so?!

Answer (score 11):

Check [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit), the Git plugin for Eclipse. It's out of incubation since June 2011. You can see how it looks in [the user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide). Here are a few screenshots to wet your appetite:

- New files:

[image: New files to be added]

- Commit Window:

[image: Commit window]

- History View:

[image: History View]

Comment: The best option if you are using Eclipse IDE because all is integrated. Pretty and useful.

Answer (score 6):

I just started running **GitExtensions** on [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29), and it seems to work pretty well so far (running [Ubuntu 11.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal) here).

I had to install some libraries to get the compiled ZIP package to run:

- libmono-winforms2.0-cil for System.Windows.Forms
- libmono-system-ldap2.0-cil for System.DirectoryServices

  Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a packaged version for Ubuntu.

Comment: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/wiki/How-To:-run-Git-Extensions-on-Linux

Answer (score 5):

[Git GUI](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) is what I always use on Windows. It does just about everything I ever need to do in Git, and the graphical nature is invaluable for getting a good picture of what is going on.

I haven't tried it on Linux, but I doubt it is any worse there.

I think the reason there hasn't been a big push into alternative tools is that Git GUI is more than good enough for those who like to use GUIs.

Comment: I can understand that the graphical nature is invaluable, but still needed to lower the entry level barrier.

Answer (score 2):

[GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) is highly recommended. It is a cross-platform, modern and beautiful GIT client.

Comment: A free Git GUI for non-commercial use and discounted pricing for teams.

https://www.gitkraken.com/pro