# Git GUI like Bzr Explorer but for Git?

Tags: linux, git, user-interface, bazaar, git-gui

What GUI's are there for GIT that are like Bazaar Explorer?

Preferably for Linux.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/home-page-screenshot.png))</sub>

Would be great to include or link to screenshots in the answers.

If you could do each app as one answer, they could be individually voted on.

Comment: Have you tried looking other questions here about GUIs for git?  For example, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516720/git-gui-client-for-linux) asks specifically about Linux clients - one of the answers there also links to [the canonical list of git user interfaces](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools).  If there are specific things about the Bazaar Explorer interface that you're looking for, it might help to list those in your question.

Comment: Yes I have looked, from what I see, the best matches were:
SmartGIT, TortoiseSVN (recent GIT support), and EGit. SmartGIT seems most similar but is proprietary.

Comment: Basically Bazaar Explorer is great at hand holding most steps of the process, no syntax needs learning so developers can just use it.

Comment: I ask because I want to know what others think who are aware of the richness of Bazaar Explorer.

Comment: I have to admit, even though I like git, Canonical came up with a pretty awesome interface for bzr that's going to be hard to match.

Comment: Another possibly duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141611/a-pretty-and-feature-rich-git-gui-for-linux

Answer (score 5):

Install [bzr-git plugin](https://launchpad.net/bzr-git) for bzr and then simply use Bazaar Explorer to work with your git repositories.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I wondered if it was possible..
So you don't think I'd need Push support?

Comment: @Luke Stanley: Yes, that's a problem. I think you should be able to use `bzr dpush` instead to push to your master git repository from local one. It's could be invoked from "All commands" dialog, or you can customize toolbar. So, yes, native Git GUI will be much better.

Comment: ok thanks, I will have to get around to trying it out and will update the answer when I know more.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is qgit.
https://github.com/tibirna/qgit

The 2.9 version works on very old systems like OS X 10.6.8.