# Is there a way to view complete git diff using a GUI tool?

Tags: git, user-interface, diff

Is there a combination of a GUI diff viewer and a git configuration that would allow me to view all modified files at once? Currently I use `git difftool` and it invokes a separate diff viewer for each file.
It would be great if there was a way to force git to put both versions of all modified files somewhere and invoke the diff tool for all of them only once.

Comment: Do you want to see all of them in the same window, or do you want to issue only a single command to ``diff`` them all? If it is the former, to what end?

Comment: I like to use p4merge as such a tool, but it opens one window per conflict, and I am not sure any other tool does what you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [git difftool, open all diff files immediately, not in serial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With svn I use KDE "kompare" program to view all files at ones.

Like here:

```
svn diff > output
kompare output
```

or directly:

```
svn diff | kompare
```

also there are Gnom "meld", which supposed to do the same thing (but I didn't tried it yet).

The same should be applicable for git.

Answer (score 1):

Since [git 1.7.11](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1307164), `difftool` supports directory comparison:

> "`git difftool`" learned the "`--dir-diff`" option to spawn external diff tools that can compare two directory hierarchies at a time after populating two temporary directories, instead of running an instance of the external tool once per a file pair.

So you could combine it with an external diff tool, as mentioned in "[use `Winmerge` inside of Git to file `diff`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1884517/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Atlassian SourceTree`. It's a free Git Client for `Windows` & `Mac`.

I'm using it since the beta. And it's really the best tool ive ever used for git in my opinion.

[image]

[image]

Say goodbye to the command line – use the full capability of Git and Mercurial in the SourceTree desktop app. Manage all your repositories, hosted or local, through SourceTree's simple interface.

[image]

More informations under:

http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/03/19/introducing-sourcetree-git-client-microsoft-windows/
http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Bazaar Explorer is quite nice. I think you can get it work with Git by using Plugin (Bazaar Git Support Plugin).

[Git GUI like Bzr Explorer but for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009280/git-gui-like-bzr-explorer-but-for-git)