# Gui client for Git

Tags: git, user-interface, version-control, bazaar

First of all, this is not a duplicated question.

I'm using [Bazaar Explorer](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/explorer/en/) for bzr version control. It works fine and fits all my needs but recently I found that Git works better than bzr so I decided to use it, but I face a problem with Git usability because most Git's Gui not user friendly as Bazaar Explorer, so I want your advice based on a practical experience which best git's GUI user friendly or which one is most similar to Bazaar Explorer?

PS

- I already read [suggested Gui tools for git](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#Graphical_Interfaces)
- I prefer to get the answers from people used Bazaar Explorer before or at least test it.
- I don't use commercial products at all.

Comment: What platform? Also, I bet there are duplicates of this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git GUI like Bzr Explorer but for Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009280/git-gui-like-bzr-explorer-but-for-git) and [A pretty and feature rich git GUI for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141611/a-pretty-and-feature-rich-git-gui-for-linux)

Comment: As I said above this is not a duplicate... both links talk about "git repository viewer" not full repository manager. `Bazaar Explorer` works as full bzr repository manager where all suggested solutions aren't more than repository viewers `gitg` , `giggle` or `QGit` .... I'm using Linux sorry I didn't mention that. By the way for Windows I found `TortoiseGit` pretty nice but unfortunately it' working under Windows.